# still get error on has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, .net-core

I have a asp.net core 3 application with Angular 8. So in Angular I have this method:

```
 getValues() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:44323/api/Values/').subscribe(response => {
      this.values = response;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And my cs file looks like this:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddCors();

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        }
    }
```

So I am doing the UseCors thing. But I still get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44323/api/Values/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Of  course I googled this error. THat is why I have used the UseCors thing. But is what they recommonded. But I still get this error.

So I am stuck. Will be nice if somebody can  tell me what I do wrong.

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
[EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private protected DataContext _dataContext;
        public ValuesController( DataContext dataContext)
        {
            this._dataContext = dataContext;
        }
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
        public async Task <IActionResult> GetValues()
        {
            var values = await _dataContext.Values.ToListAsync();

            return Ok(values);

        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task <IActionResult> GetValue(int id)
        {
            var value = await _dataContext.Values.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            return Ok(value);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddCors();
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44323").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());

        }
    }
```

But then I will get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Endpoint DatingApp.API.Controllers.ValuesController.GetValues (DatingApp.API) contains CORS metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports CORS.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseCors() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingCorsMiddlewareException(Endpoint endpoint)
```

Comment: hey, have you tried to use a proxy redirection ? https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: I didnt tried that. But oke, This has to been working. I don't undertand why it doesnt't work

Comment: well cors request are always hard to deal with

Comment: tell me if it work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to have **`AllowAnyOrigin`**

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

or pass the origin

```
 app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins('https://localhost:44323').AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried that. But still get the error

Comment: you need to add .AllowCredentials();

Comment: and remove duplicate UseCors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564786/unable-to-access-the-webapi-from-angular-8-application

Comment: Oke, you need to add .AllowCredentials(); didnt tried that. But where I have to add this?

Comment: at the end of the above statement, please check above link

Comment: ? Where is the comment? Why somebody vote on my post??

Answer (score 3):

Oke, I solved finaly!!

I didnt knew that. The trick was that I did it like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseCors();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

So between routing and Authorization.
```

And the person who voted on my post in not good way. Shame you!!