# ASP.NET Core 7 Chrome error "Ensure private network requests are only made to resources that allow them"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cors, preflight, private-network-access

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application running on intranet that uses Windows authentication.

Recently I made some updates and included model validation for all models as part of securing application.

After the updates I am getting a warning in Chrome:

> Ensure private network requests are only made to resources that allow them

Can anyone explain where this error is coming from please? The app has no APIs it is all self contained normal ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I enabled CORS to allow only the origin of the app. This did not fix the issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73553149/why-preflight-requests-fail-only-in-chrome-and-then-they-work-after-few-tries). Besides,"Chrome is deprecating access to private network endpoints from non-secure websites as part of the Private Network Access specification." you can look [this](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/) to know more.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. This has helped.