# Google Chrome 123 Update: Chrome is making preflight check for document/Redirect type GET request

Tags: http, cors, google-chrome-devtools, http-redirect, preflight

After the chrome new update, I am facing a CORS exception in my application. Upon investigation, I found that it is doing a CORS preflight check to a document/Redirect type GET request, which it didn't do before.
I checked other browsers like Microsoft Edge, where it is not the case, i.e., edge didn't do a preflight check for the same request.

Anybody has any idea on this?

The expectation is there should be no CORS preflight check for a document type request irrespective of the http method.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/40263397.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer. I guess this is related to Private Network Access

Refer these links:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/#what-is-private-network-access-pna

[Why preflight requests fail only in Chrome and then they work after few tries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73553149/why-preflight-requests-fail-only-in-chrome-and-then-they-work-after-few-tries?rq=2)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv#:~:text=The%20Origin%20spec%20indicates%20that,from%20a%20hosted%20web%20page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv#:%7E:text=The%20Origin%20spec%20indicates%20that,from%20a%20hosted%20web%20page).