# I get CORS Error on SignalR hub with Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, signalr

I have a hub with signalR and i want to secure it with the [Authorize] attribute. The hub can gets the user from the JWT token and gives me 401 when the token is invalid so all seems to be ok. But when i publish it to dev environment and the the frontend client connects to the hub it gives an CORS error.

I have a testing client in local and i use it to connect to localhost and even to the hub of development env. From that testing client everything works fine, but not from the frontend of dev environment.

If i remove the [Authorize] attribute all works fine again. No cors error and still can get the user from the token but the hub its not actually secured.

So i assume there has to be some additional configuration that i have missed.

I have tried different configuration of cors policy and none of them changed anything.
I also have tried to add the cors policy manually to the hub:

```
app.MapHub<TestHub>("/hubs/test")
                .RequireCors("CorsPolicy")
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hello, were you managed to resolve the issue? Because I hit the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I set the logs to Verbose and got the message in the log: OPTIONS requests are not supported.

I added the middleware from this post (Accepted answer):

[Enable OPTIONS header for CORS on .NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199757/enable-options-header-for-cors-on-net-core-web-api)

Because I am using Authorization header, full block of code with if in the BeginInvoke method in the OptionsMiddleware looks like this:

```
if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { (string)context.Request.Headers["Origin"] });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, x-signalr-user-agent" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
    }
```

Hope it helps, because I was stuck almost two days on this.